# Backpropagation issues

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have a couple of questions about how to code the backpropagation algorithm of neural networks:

The topology of my networks is an input layer, hidden layer and output layer. Both the hidden layer and output layer have sigmoid functions.

1. First of all, should I use the bias?
   To where should I connect the bias
   in my network? Should I put one bias
   unit per layer in both the hidden
   layer and output layer? What about
   the input layer?
2. In this [link](http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html), they define the last delta as the input - output and they backpropagate the deltas as can be seen in the figure. They hold a table to put
   all the deltas before actually
   propagating the errors in a
   feedforward fashion. Is this a
   departure from the standard
   backpropagation algorithm?
   [image]
3. Should I decrease the learning
   factor over time?
4. In case anyone knows, is Resilient
   Propagation an online or batch
   learning technique?

Thanks

**edit:** One more thing. In the following picture, d f1(e) / de, assuming I'm using the sigmoid function, is f1(e) * [1- f1(e)], right?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question needs to be specified a bit more thoroughly... What is your need? Generalization or memorization? Are you anticipating a complex pattern matching data set, or a continuous-domain input-output relationship? Here are my $0.02:

1. I would suggest you leave a bias neuron in just in case you need it. If it is deemed unnecessary by the NN, training should drive the weights to negligible values. It will connect to every neuron in the layer up ahead, but is not connected to from any neuron in the preceding layer.
2. The equation looks like standard backprop as far as I can tell.
3. It is hard to generalize whether your learning rate needs to be decreased over time. The behaviour is highly data-dependent. The smaller your learning rate, the more stable your training will be. However, it can be *painfully* slow, especially if you're running it in a scripting language like I did once upon a time.
4. Resilient backprop (or RProp in MATLAB) should handle both online and batch training modes.

I'd just like to add that you might want to consider alternative activation functions if possible. The sigmoid function doesn't always give the best results...

Comment: My objective is generalization. I am actually using right now tanh. What would you suggest besides those?

Comment: A combination of tanh and linear functions for the hidden and output neurons respectively is good for continuous function mappings. Step functions are good for pattern recognition. Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 3):

1. It varies. Personally, I don't see much of a reason for bias, but I haven't studied NN enough to actually make a valid case for or against them. I'd try it out to and test results.
2. That's correct. Backpropagation involves calculation of deltas first, and then propagating them across the network.
3. Yes. Learning factor should be decreased over time. However, with BP, you can hit local, incorrect plateaus, so sometimes around the 500th iteration, it makes sense to reset the learning factor to the intial rate.
4. I can't answer that.....never heard anything about RP.

Comment: Re 4) I _think_ RP can be online or batch